# Restored Windows Vista Recovery Partition Image not booting - clonezilla

Tags: boot, windows-vista, clonezilla, bootrepair

I've followed the first two of [these](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php) guides from clonezilla.org, but: applied to a Windows Vista Recovery partition; partition-to-image rather than disk-to-image. I wiped out the entire disk after saving the partition. I was able to restore the partition but unfortunately It didn't boot. I have no CDs.

I tried [boot-repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/) tool and [this link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25987341/) is the Pastebin. The disk is /dev/sda. It still does not boot, either pressing F9, ESC or F2.

Did I do something wrong? How can I restore the Vista Recovery partition properly (in order then to reinstall Vista)?